# Youtube api: изменить опцию "Не показывать информацию о моих подписках"

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth2

Мое приложение работает через `Google OAuth`. Возможно ли изменить пользовательские настройки приватности, в частности пункт "*Не показывать информацию о моих подписках*"?

Comment: Our working language is Russian. Please translate your question into Russian or move it to intl. SO.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку